# EXC_ARITHMETIC when using UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes in iOS 9 (Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

I am getting EXC_ARITHMETIC error while running my app in Xcode 7 ,iOS 9 . But its working nicely in down editions (Xcode 6.4 , iOS 8.4)

Please find the code below

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowlayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionViewLayout;
    NSUInteger count = _tripButtons.count;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
        UIView *tripButton = [_tripButtons pointerAtIndex:i];
        if (tripButton)
     {
            CGRect frame = tripButton.frame;
               // Getting error with below line
                UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layout = [flowlayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
                frame.origin.x = layout.frame.origin.x;
                frame.origin.y = layout.frame.origin.y;
                tripButton.frame = frame;



        }
    }
```

I am confused with the error . Is this error coming due to bugs in my code or might be due to my upgrade. Please guide me...

Comment: Does it occur when your section is empty ? I've got the same problem when there is no item in my section.

Comment: same issue, have you solve yours ?

Comment: Did anybody find solution? same issue here